# javascript color toggles between two links working, not resetting when they need to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links popularity and new. if I click "popularity" it should turn green until I click "new". and vice versa for "new". And this works great. But thing is when I click home button that's in my navbar, the green color on the link should be gone. they should go back to the color they were before they are clicked.

my code

```
<div id="Space">
  <ul id="shouldwork">
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="norang" href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">popularity</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="updated" href="/?sort=date&page=1"  style="text-decoration:none;">new</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <script>
//on page load
var ul_li_a = $("ul#shouldwork>li>a");
var lastClickTag = localStorage.getItem("last_clicked");

ul_li_a.css("color", "black");
if(lastClickTag){
  $("."+lastClickTag).css("color", "green")
}



$('ul#shouldwork>li').on("click", function(){      
  ul_li_a.css("color", "black");
  $(this).children("a").css("color", "green"); 
  localStorage.setItem("last_clicked", $(this).children("a").attr("class"));  
});
</script>
```

and in navbar I have

```
<div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">home</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with an .active class in CSS in order to make it more modular and easy to understand. Then, I would change the color based on your query strings, rather than using local storage.

I didn't have a way to test this so let me know if it works. If not, let me know what error is displaying in the console. I'm sure I may have missed something in the JS.

Here is a codepen if you'd rather look at it there: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVGYWE?editors=1111

HTML (links are removed as they broke in codepen, added class .link for better targeting in jQuery)

```
<div id="Space">
  <ul class="shouldwork">
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="link norang" href="#">popularity</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link updated" href="#">new</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  color: navy;
  text-decoration: none;  
}

.link.active {
  color: green;
}
```

jQuery

```
// change on click
var link = $('.link');

link.on("click", function(){      
  // remove any active classes
  link.removeClass("active");
  // add active class to link that was clicked
  $(this).addClass("active");
});


// set up get query strings from URL
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// see if the page is indeed sorted
var sort = getParameterByName('sort')

// if it has a query string of sort=score, make that active
if ( sort == "score") {
  $(".sort a").addClass("active");
}

// if it has a query string of sort=date, make that active
if ( sort == "date") {
  $(".date a").addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should they go back to the original color? You never told them to.

```
$('.navbar-brand').on('click',function(){
    ul_li_a.css("color", "black");
})
```

Comment: that's the first thing I tried, you mean adding that function to the bottom of my javascript right? this doesn't work...

Comment: Based on the code you've given us there's no reason why my answer shouldn't work. It's pretty cut and dry, there must be an external reason. Can you make us a jsFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: Because he's saving the "last clicked" item to local storage so even when he goes home, it's still grabbing that item from local storage. You need to remove the last clicked from local storage when they go home (or anywhere else for that matter) or do it a different way. I proposed using the parameters in your URL in my answer as it'll allows you to build add'l pages without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize both .addClass and .removeClass, and create another CSS class that changes the color back when you click the home button. This would be more seamless if you took the css out of your js code, and just use these two methods to switch between the classes you need on the home button click event.

edit: or what he said ^. There are many options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description, and a quick scan of your code, it looks like you are properly setting the color when the two items themselves are clicked, but you have no function to handle *unsetting* the color when something else is clicked ... i.e. in your function that fires on-click, just check that if neither is used, clear the green color.

Alternatively, you could use something like is used [here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/clear_links_to/) ... i.e. a conditional something along the lines of this: `if(a[i].href.split("#")[0] == window.location.href.split("#")[0])`. Then, just apply the green color if either of your two links are active.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `id`s for links, change your code as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/0n2g0Lxm/).

```
var ul_li_a = $("ul#shouldwork>li>a");
var lastClickTag = localStorage.getItem("last_clicked");

if(lastClickTag){
  $("#"+lastClickTag).addClass('green');
}

ul_li_a.on("click", function(){      
  ul_li_a.removeClass('green');
  $(this).addClass('green'); 
  localStorage.setItem("last_clicked", this.id);
});

$('.navbar-brand').click( function() {
    ul_li_a.removeClass('green');
    $("#"+lastClickTag).addClass('green');
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="shouldwork">
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a id="norang" href=".." style="text-decoration:none;">popularity</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a id="updated" href=".."  style="text-decoration:none;">new</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: with this code, the link doesn't turn green when I click one

Comment: make sure you copy js, html and css.  I had to remove hrefs though to make that demo, so you will need them back

Comment: yeah I copied exactly same, you can see my whole index.html

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I did....even with the code I provided in this quetion, in fiddle everything works fine...I'm definitely doing some thing wrong..

Comment: Is your script in the bottom of the page, below all html markup?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing your `lastClickTag` from the local storage must resolve your issue along with this code.

```
$('.navbar-brand').on('click',function(){
    localStorage.removeItem("last_clicked"); 
})
```

remove this local storage. So your `if(lastClickTag){` function will not be executed, And your color will remain black.